# excel vba macro assign checkboxes to cells in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, macros

I am trying to run a macro that will assign all checkboxes in a sheet to the same cell in an other sheet.
But i am not good in vba (never done it actually, so read not good as... ).
I do understand some progamming so this is what i came up with so far, but i am stuck:

```
    Sub LinkCheckBoxes()
Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    With chk
        .LinkedCell = Worksheets("data").Address
    End With

Next chk

End Sub
```

This does not work and I am unable to find the correct code to make it work.
It only has to run once, to set the links as they are now unlinked.

(if it runs it will take care of 500 checkboxes for me...)

Thanks

Comment: are they `ActiveX` checkboxes ?

Comment: Your address is wrong, it's a sheet, not a range something like `.LinkedCell = "Data!$K$5"`

Comment: @ShaiRado They are not activeX checkboxes, but form ones.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes something like that has to be the fact for the checkbox in K5, but it need to run for all the checkboxes in the sheet.

Comment: So you want to know how to loop sheets and then work on them?  Look a the `worksheets` collection

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I need it to run once for 1 sheet, wich contains 500 checkboxes and give each checkbox a link to a cell on a sheet called "data". i.e. checkbox on A1 should link to data!A1

Comment: so what is the issue you are having? your linked cell ref needs to be changed to the correct syntax, use the suggestion from rory for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to link them to the cells that they are over, but on a different sheet:

```
Sub LinkCheckBoxes()
   Dim chk As CheckBox

   For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
      chk.LinkedCell = "Data!" & chk.Topleftcell.address
   Next chk

End Sub
```

Note that this uses the cell under the top left corner of the checkbox shape, which may not be the same as the cell the actual checkbox appears to be over.

Comment: <3 Thanks!!! This worked exactly as I wanted. + ed the comment(it said it was registered but i am to low lvl to show) and marked as answer.